# How to apply Google Maps API v3 continent/land color style

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to style my google map so it blends in nicely in my webtheme. Here is the style I'm currently using. anyone knows how to make all land displaying in a specific hex color? I did try this with "administrative.country" featureType without any luck.

```
var myStyle = [
   {
     featureType: "administrative",
     elementType: "labels",
     stylers: [
       { visibility: "off" }
     ]
   },{
     featureType: " administrative.country",
     elementType: "geometry",
     stylers: [
       { hue:"#6E6E6E"}
     ]
   },{
     featureType: "poi",
     elementType: "labels",
     stylers: [
       { visibility: "off" }
     ]
   },{
     featureType: "water",
     elementType: "labels",
     stylers: [
       { visibility: "off" }
     ]
   },{
     featureType: "road",
     elementType: "labels",
     stylers: [
       { visibility: "off" }
     ]
   }
 ];
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was able to mess around with the style wizard [here](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) to determine you want to use the landscape feature like this:

```
[ 
  { 
    featureType: "landscape", 
    elementType: "geometry", 
    stylers: [ 
      { hue: "#ff2200" }, 
      { saturation: 85 }, 
      { lightness: -42 } 
    ] 
  } 
]
```

[Sample using that style.](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=0,0&zoom=3&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap&style=feature:landscape%7Celement:geometry%7Chue:0xff2200%7Csaturation:85%7Clightness:-42)

Answer (score 5):

You can use http://googlemapscolorizr.stadtwerk.org/ to test the map. It also Calculates the saturation and lightness to display the correct Hex color.

Answer (score 0):

Styling your google map has never been easier.
[mapstylr.com](http://www.mapstylr.com)

Comment: I'm not sure if I would say 'never been easier' - the insane amount of options makes all of these tools really difficult to figure out. Is it possible to make all the water one solid colour and ALL the land one solid colour by hex code?